# trying d3.js chord diargram - shows TypeError: imports is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, chord-diagram

I am trying to learn using d3 chord diagram. Original script in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1046712#index.html

But as I try to use the code locally I am getting TypeError: imports is undefined

My index.html has the following code. I have created a readme.json file with exact data form http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1046712/readme.json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.chord {
  fill-opacity: .67;
```

}

```
</style>

<script>

function asd(){
 alert("asd");
 var outerRadius = 960 / 2,
 innerRadius = outerRadius - 130;

var fill = d3.scale.category20c();

var chord = d3.layout.chord()
    .padding(.04)
    .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
    .sortChords(d3.descending);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(innerRadius + 20);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", outerRadius * 2)
    .attr("height", outerRadius * 2)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

d3.json("readme.json", function(error, imports) {
  var indexByName = d3.map(),
      nameByIndex = d3.map(),
      matrix = [],
      n = 0;

  // Returns the Flare package name for the given class name.
  function name(name) {
    return name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")).substring(6);
  }

  // Compute a unique index for each package name.
  imports.forEach(function(d) {
    if (!indexByName.has(d = name(d.name))) {
      nameByIndex.set(n, d);
      indexByName.set(d, n++);
    }
  });

  // Construct a square matrix counting package imports.
  imports.forEach(function(d) {
    var source = indexByName.get(name(d.name)),
        row = matrix[source];
    if (!row) {
     row = matrix[source] = [];
     for (var i = -1; ++i < n;) row[i] = 0;
    }
    d.imports.forEach(function(d) { row[indexByName.get(name(d))]++; });
  });

  chord.matrix(matrix);

  var g = svg.selectAll(".group")
      .data(chord.groups)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "group");

  g.append("path")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
      .attr("d", arc);

  g.append("text")
      .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
            + "translate(" + (innerRadius + 26) + ")"
            + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
      })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
      .text(function(d) { return nameByIndex.get(d.index); });

  svg.selectAll(".chord")
      .data(chord.chords)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "chord")
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.source.index)).darker(); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.source.index); })
      .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(innerRadius));

});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", outerRadius * 2 + "px");
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="asd()">
asd
</body>
</html>
```

I use apache in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to set up a web server on a local machine in order to run such examples locally.

A good explanation is [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch04.html).

I usually use python SimpleHTTPServer.

Also, you need to access your example via localhost:{port number}, not via file system.

There are few more gotchas, but I believe this would be sufficient for you to start.

Comment: I do use apache as my webserver.

Comment: ok, cool, do you access your example via localhost:[port-number], port number is what you set for apache webserver?

Comment: also, you can try different browsers.. some of them are very picky in such setups, for security reasons.